# iptables rules for mitmproxy

Tags: routing, iptables, wireshark

I'm looking for the correct iptables rules for the following scenario.

Router R running ddwrt (so I can set iptables rules, but can't install mitmproxy / wireshark)

Device A which is sending traffic I want to analyze to the internet.
Device B running Ubuntu on which I have mitmproxy and wireshark.
Many other devices on the network connected to R which I don't want to disrupt.

How do I set up the rules so that traffic from A (and only traffic from A) is routed to device B? I don't have any control over the device A besides setting to which wifi AP it connects.

Edit: I'm doing this in my home network to my own devices.

Comment: You can use switch with port mirroring feature

Comment: @Nikolai, could you explain?

Comment: If device A connected using WiFi you can try to use wireless sniffer. If you can connect device A to R using ethernet then you can put switch between A and R and connect B to mirrored port on that switch

Answer (score 0):

First you have to route traffic to your device B, have a look at `arpspoof`. Then you have to apply firewall rule to set-up a transparent proxy with `mitmproxy`.

Nonetheless be aware that this kind of behaviour are highly illegal in many states. Do this only if you do it on educational purposes on **your** equipment.

Comment: I edited the post to say that it is my equipment.

Isn't `arpspoof` a more complicated tool? Can't it be done with iptables rules on the router?

Comment: In fact if A and B are on the same network and B is not a A's gateway there is no reason for A to send traffic to B. With Iptables you'll be able to redirect/analyze incoming traffic but if B doesn't get traffic in the first place you will have nothing to analyze/redirect. At best you'll see broadcast packet that's all.

Comment: that's why I'm interested how to redirect the traffic on the gateway so it reaches B as if B was A's gateway.

Comment: so look at arpspoof command ;)